# hls implementation in wavesurfer videojs using m3u8

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http-live-streaming, video.js, wavesurfer.js

I want to implement hls to show audio wave in videojs wavesurfer. The file format is .m3u8 and I code in React, this is my code:

```
    const wavesurferNode = document.getElementById("wavesurfer");
    if (wavesurferNode) {
      const audio = document.getElementById("audio");
      if (Hls.isSupported()) {
        var hls = new Hls();
        hls.loadSource("https://stream.mux.com/Z49yBPngc5Cs5w3OoMJOVkrgHeWIhaaALbRBSE38VbU.m3u8");
        hls.attachMedia(audio);
        hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function () {
          const wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
            container: wavesurferNode,
            backend: "MediaElement",
            msDisplayMax: 10,
            autoplay: true,
            barGap: 2,
            barRadius: true,
            waveHeight: "100",
            cursorWidth: 2,
            interact: true,
            waveColor: 'red',
            progressColor: 'blue',
            cursorColor: 'black',
            hideScrollbar: true,
          });

          const player = videojs("audio", {
            plugins: {
              wavesurfer: wavesurfer,
            },
          });
    });


//render
              <div
                data-vjs-player
                id="wavesurfer"
              >
                <audio
                  className={`video-js vjs-default-skin`}
                  controls={true}
                  id="audio"
                ></audio>
              </div>
```

in this code WaveSurfer imported from `wavesurfer.js` and videojs imported from `video.js`.
Using this code, the audio file is played, but nothing is displayed on the screen. The error displayed is as follows:
`VIDEOJS: ERROR: TypeError: this.Backend is not a constructor`